# How do I print the first letter in the second word in a list?

Tags: python, list, slice

so I have a list of words:

```
list = [name1, name2, name3,...]
```

I want to print out the first letter of the second word. How would I go about doing that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can extract the second word `list[1]` and then the first letter like this:

```
list[1][0]
```